# Miigrating 3.4.4 to 3.4.5 : warning JFolder: :delete: Path is not a folder. Path: /plugins/quickicon/eosnotify

Tags: joomla-3.4, update

I got this warning when migrating Joomla from 3.4.4 to 3.4.5:

> JFolder: :delete: Path is not a folder. Path:.../plugins/quickicon/eosnotify

Does anyone know what it means?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks it's a Joomla 2.5 plugin: https://github.com/crusonweb/eosnotify

Comment: OK : end of support for Joomla 2.5... Migration to 3.4 let some dust. Many thanks for your mail !